# What IP addresses/WebSites need to be unblocked to install and run jenkins on a server which is running behind a Firewall

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, ssh, firewall

I am installing Jenkins in a organizations system, which has Firewall restrictions, bcz of that I believe I am getting

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.16.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/abcdWebApp-Build-War/pom.xml to com.xyz/def-abcd/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/def-abcd-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE

So I have contacted my IT Support team, they asked me to provide list of IP/websites that need to be unblocked, can you please help me on that to find out the list of websites

Comment: This needs to be accessible: `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`  otherwise it will not work... furthermore in a corporate environment I strongly recommend to install a repository manager so you have only a single access to the internet (central repository) and no need to access the central repo from different workstations/ci servers and also client machines...

Comment: Yes, I have already added https://repo.maven.apache.org in allowed site, but its still failing, I guess I have to provide a list of urls

Comment: Is your system behind a proxy or the connection is direct to the firewall and then to internet?

Comment: Yes, its behind a proxy, in jenkins I have mentioned the proxy and port to get the connection to the IPs. But all the IPs that need to be connected from Jenkins I have to specify to the IT team, so that they can unblock those Sites/IP